# Canvas toBlob is not recognized as a function in safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari, html5-canvas

I am able to download an image in Chrome & Firefox using the code below but in Safari it's throwing this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'canvas.toBlob(blobCallback('wallpaperdeae'))')

```
$("#save").click(function(){

   function blobCallback(iconName) {
        return function (b) {

            var a = document.getElementById('download');
            a.download = iconName + ".jpg";
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(b);
        }
    }
    canvas.toBlob(blobCallback('wallpaperdeae'));

});
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think the toBlob method is supported in Safari:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Browser_compatibility

According to this it's only available in Chrome 50+ and Firefox (19+ for basic support and 25+ for Image quality parameter) with some basic support in IE 10 and above.

So there's no support whatsoever for Safari.

**Edit: According to the referenced URL support was added for the toBlob method in Safari 11 which came out on September 19th 2017**

Comment: thanks Dibsy Jr, can you suggest any other alternative to fix this.

Comment: Depends on what browser versions you need to support but you could always use:

https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob

Which acts as a polyfill for the toBlob method in the browser

Comment: Also please select this as the chosen answer and vote it up if it's helped you at all.

Comment: It now appears that there is in fact some support in Safari (per the referenced URL).

Comment: Thanks @thesquaregroot i've added an Edit saying when it was added.

Answer (score 3):

There is a ["low performance polyfill based on `toDataURL`" posted on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)

```
if (!HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob) {
  Object.defineProperty(HTMLCanvasElement.prototype, 'toBlob', {
    value: function (callback, type, quality) {
      var canvas = this;
      setTimeout(function() {

        var binStr = atob( canvas.toDataURL(type, quality).split(',')[1] ),
            len = binStr.length,
            arr = new Uint8Array(len);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
          arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        callback( new Blob( [arr], {type: type || 'image/png'} ) );

      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not work in Edge. It changes the error from "not a function" to "function expected". But still wont work. I have yet to find a toBlob polyfill that works in edge.

Comment: Interestingly, this worked in Edge for a recent test I did, so it's possible something changed since April.